# agile toolkit 4.3 installation error

Tags: atk4

I have downloaded the new version(4.3) but when I go to the

```
http://localhost/agiletoolkit/
```

this error is shown:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in phar://D:/wamp/www/agiletoolkit/agiletoolkit-sandbox.phar/lib/AgileToolkit/Installer.php on line 73
```

could you please help me how to install the new version?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please show us the code of the line that is causing the problem? It tells you about invalid syntax..

Comment: From where did you downloaded that version? Latest from Github or from webpage?

Comment: I'm have downloaded the archive from http://www4.agiletoolkit.org/download

Comment: the line 73 is: if(!$_GET['step']){
            if($this->app->sandbox->auto_config->getConfig('certificate','')){
                $this->redirect($this->url(null, ['step' => 'finish']));
            }
        }

Comment: Well actually it was bug in installer (which should be 5.3 compatible). I have resolved it and you can retry again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New ATK 4.3 version mostly use new PHP array notation `[1,2,3]` instead of old `array(1,2,3)` which is available only if you use PHP 5.4 and up.

So, please upgrade your PHP installation to at least 5.4 and then try again.

Comment: On the other hand ATK 4.3 should still be compatible with PHP 5.3. Some incompatibilities are fixed now, but still some can happen. If you find issues, please create "new issue" in Github atk4 repository.